# Faster alternative to math/rand that is not synchronized

Tags: go

I'm trying to optimise my genetic algorithm. This uses a lot of random number selection (random mutations, etc).

I decided to use the CPU profiler:

```golang
import (
    "runtime/pprof"
)

var cpuprofile = flag.String("cpuprofile", "", "write cpu profile to file")

func main() {

    if *cpuprofile != "" {
        fmt.Println(*cpuprofile)
        f, err := os.Create(*cpuprofile)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        _ = pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
        defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    }
    ***app logic***
```

I was surprised to see that one of the top contributors to the CPU usage was `sync.(*Mutex).Unlock`, notably because **I have not used threads or goroutines at any point in my application**.

[image: pprof result]

Some digging revealed the bottleneck is caused by the default source in math/rand being synchronized.

Is there a faster way for me to generate random numbers with functions that are not synchronized/blocking?

True randomness/accurate pseudo-randomness is not so important for this application, but it'd be preferred if I didn't get the exact same numbers multiple times in close succession.

Comment: Have you tried https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#New ?

Comment: I had not, I'll give that a try. Thanks

Comment: Excellent! Creating a new rand source in a few places reduced my execution time from 1.29 mins to 55s, and eliminated the Mutex and lockedSource functions from the pprof trace entirely. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found, the default "randomness source" for the `math/rand` package is a *locked* source, suitable for use in concurrent goroutines.  You will need to create one new source per goroutine using the [`NewSource` function](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#NewSource), and then one random number generator from that, using [New](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#New).  The pseudo-random numbers from this new generator will work the same way as the (single) locked source except that each generator will produce its own stream of identically-generated numbers if started from the same seed.

You'll therefore want to ensure that each *seed* you provide to `NewSource` is unique, so that each stream is different.

Comment: Thanks for providing this detail. Out of curiosity, is there much of an overhead to using NewSource followed by New? Is this something I should avoid doing too regularly?

Comment: Both functions create a pointer to a new value, meaning they will most likely cause a heap allocation.  You can check the function source code by clicking the function name on the documentation page.

Comment: What @HymnsForDisco said; I'd recommend that if you're going to run N goroutines to take advantage of N-parallel-able-generation, you create N random number generators from N seeded sources. After that you won't need any further creation, since there are only N parallel routines running. You can get the seeds from anywhere, though for actual randomness, use `/dev/urandom` or the crypto random or something.

Comment: Thanks for the practical suggestions. Makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for fast high quality pseudo-random numbers in Go, I've created a package that (I think, but I am obviously biased) goes about as fast as you can in Go without sacrificing quality (and significantly improving it compared to `math/rand`): [pgregory.net/rand](https://pkg.go.dev/pgregory.net/rand) ([benchmarks](https://github.com/flyingmutant/rand#benchmarks)).

In addition to avoiding any synchronization, it uses faster algorithms and avoid the `Source` interface to make inlining possible.